# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.294'

Tags: python

I want to generate a random int and then use time.sleep().
I want it to generate something like 0.123 randomly.
Here is my code:

```
s = f"0.{str(random.randint(111, 333))}"
s = int(s)
time.sleep(s)
```

I am getting the error:

```
    time.sleep(s)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.198'
```

I tried a lot of things, different ways of formatting it etc. No luck

Comment: Why do you think this should work? You're trying to convert the string `'0.198'` to an integer. See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: do you mean float? integers must be whole numbers.

Comment: If you want a random int, why generate a random float ?

Comment: or conversely, if you want a value between `0.111` and `0.333`, why generate an int? you could do `random.random() * 0.222 + 0.111` for a random value on this interval.

Comment: to convert a float number (as string type) to int we need to use float type as argument. modify your code:  s = float(f"0.{str(random.randint(111, 333))}").  the result of the conversion to int will always be 0 in this case, since the generated numbers all start with 0.xxx.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question? Please read [ask]. As other comments have noted, what you're saying doesn't really make sense. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Beside the point, but `str()` is redundant there since it's inside an f-string.

Comment: @lroth Please don't post answers in the comments, post an answer instead. Although FWIW, you don't need to bother converting to string at all when you could just do `s = random.randint(111, 333) / 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a floating point number (0.xxx) to an int.

What you need to do is convert it to a float instead:

```
s = float(s)
```

Comment: It's worth clarifying that it's not a float; it's a string *representing* a *real* number.